# Continuous scripts reloading on uWSGI

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, uwsgi

Trying to solve it in 2 days in a row.
I have this only script on my html page:

```
function show()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "index.py",
            cache: false,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=windows-1251",
            success: function(html){
                $("#content").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
    function parse()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url: "parser.py",
            cache: false,
        });
    }
        setInterval(show(),1000);
        setInterval(parse(),10000);
</script>
```

It's deployed on VPS with uWSGI+nginx.
The trouble is: on server, when sending ajax requests (index.py, parser.py) with loading the page it сauses calling all js scripts (including bootstrap and jquery in <head>) [again and again](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPLc6.png) without delay.
But on local python http cgi server it works absolutely fine.
May be this happens because of wsgi.py content?

```
def application(environ, start_response):
start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/html')])
return '''%ENTIRE HTML CODE OF THE PAGE%'''
```

Comment: Your javascript code (btw, you should use javascript tag in your question, rather than python which is doing nothing here) is loading parser.py and index.py _again and again_, as you put it, because of the `setInterval`. It is absolutely unclear whether that means javascript files should be loaded again or not, because nothing related to them is included in the question.

Comment: It reloads without any delay, like 20 times in a sec. What about scripts: index.py generates html table depending on json file which is generating by parser.py

Comment: It does not reload 20 times in a second because of any code seen here. If I were you, I'd try removing parts of the code until it stopped reloading. I'm sure a simple "hello world" page would not reload automatically.

Comment: Yes, it is not. On local server it works fine. on uWSGI this happens. Caused by ajax requests. Without them works fine. Idk, strange thing for me